# browser.downloads.search shows up as undefined

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to list the downloads in the console using the following functions:

```
function listFiles(downloadedItems) {
    console.log(downloadedItems);
}

function getFiles() {
    var searching = browser.downloads.search({
        limit: 25,
        orderBy: ["-startTime"]
    });

    searching.then(listFiles);
}
```

When running the extension I get `undefined` for the output of the above. My Manifest file is requesting downloads access:

```
  "permissions": [
    "webNavigation",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "cookies",
    "tabs",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*",
    "ws://*/*",
    "wss://*/*",
    "storage",
    "downloads",
    "sessions"
  ],
```

How can I list the downloads to the console successfully? Side note I downloaded 25 files just for this.

Comment: Content scripts can't use most of the API so do it in the background/popup/options script.

Comment: It worked as an options script, thank you